# Xamarin.Android Bindings Library and Java Return Type Covariance

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to create a Bindings Library for the "Kotlin" library.
After adding the necessary **.jar** files to the Bindings project and building it, I got a lot of compile errors because of the **return types covariance** possible in Java, but not in C#. Some of them I could fix with transforms, but I got stuck in the following case:

One of the generated classes is this `ClassReference`, that implements an interface called `IKClass`, also generated by the bindings. That interface defines the following member:

```
global::System.Collections.ICollection Constructors {
    // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='kotlin.reflect']/interface[@name='KClass']/method[@name='getConstructors' and count(parameter)=0]"
    [Register ("getConstructors", "()Ljava/util/Collection;", "GetGetConstructorsHandler:Kotlin.Reflect.IKClassInvoker, Kotlin.Bindings")] get;
}
```

And that is the code generated for the implementation of that member, for the `ClassReference` class:

```
public unsafe global::System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<global::Kotlin.Reflect.IKFunction> Constructors {
    // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='kotlin.jvm.internal']/class[@name='ClassReference']/method[@name='getConstructors' and count(parameter)=0]"
    [Register ("getConstructors", "()Ljava/util/Collection;", "GetGetConstructorsHandler")]
    get {
        if (id_getConstructors == IntPtr.Zero)
            id_getConstructors = JNIEnv.GetMethodID (class_ref, "getConstructors", "()Ljava/util/Collection;");
        try {
            return global::Android.Runtime.JavaCollection<global::Kotlin.Reflect.IKFunction>.FromJniHandle (JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (((global::Java.Lang.Object) this).Handle, id_getConstructors), JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
        } finally {
        }
    }
}
```

So, basically, the interface expects a `ICollection` as the return type, but it's implementation is returning a `ICollection<IKFunction>`, wich leads to a compile error:

> 'ClassReference' does not implement interface member 'IKClass.Constructors'. 'ClassReference.Constructors' cannot implement 'IKClass.Constructors' because it does not have the matching return type of 'ICollection'.

That one I could fix by adding the following transform:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='kotlin.jvm.internal']/class[@name='ClassReference']/method[@name='getConstructors' and count(parameter)=0]" name="managedReturn">System.Collections.ICollection</attr>
```

But then, the generated code for the implemetation becomes:

```
public unsafe global::System.Collections.ICollection Constructors {
    // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='kotlin.jvm.internal']/class[@name='ClassReference']/method[@name='getConstructors' and count(parameter)=0]"
    [Register ("getConstructors", "()Ljava/util/Collection;", "GetGetConstructorsHandler")]
    get {
        if (id_getConstructors == IntPtr.Zero)
            id_getConstructors = JNIEnv.GetMethodID (class_ref, "getConstructors", "()Ljava/util/Collection;");
        try {
            return global::Android.Runtime.JavaCollection<global::Kotlin.Reflect.IKFunction>.FromJniHandle (JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (((global::Java.Lang.Object) this).Handle, id_getConstructors), JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
        } finally {
        }
    }
}
```

Wich leads to another error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Kotlin.Reflect.IKFunction>' to 'System.Collections.ICollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I know that happens because, except for the return type on the property, the generated code remains the same, and it's still returning a `ICollection<IKFunction>`, that won't work because `ICollection<T>` does not "inherit / implement" `ICollection`.

To solve this one, I modified my transform to rename the property, instead of changing it's return type:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='kotlin.jvm.internal']/class[@name='ClassReference']/method[@name='getConstructors' and count(parameter)=0]" name="name">ConstructorsGeneric</attr>
```

And then added a `partial class` to implement the Property defined by the interface:

```
public sealed partial class ClassReference
{
    public global::System.Collections.ICollection Constructors
    {
        get
        {
            var genericConstructors = this.ConstructorsGeneric();
            return genericConstructors.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem, is that I have a lot more errors like this one, and I don't even know if everything will work properly once I got the project building, so, here goes my question: **There is some easier way I can fix this kind of errors that I'm missing?**

There's this link on the **developer.xamarin** website that explains about customizing the bindings, and also touch on the subject of Java covariance, but I don't think it covers my scenario:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata/

Comment: did you find any easier way to do this?

Comment: No, I was creating this bindings because I needed binds for another .jar, that happens to have a dependency on Kotlin. It turns out that I didn't needed the Kotlin bindings at all, so I droped it

Comment: I am also facing this same issue. I have 1 jar file (which I need to access from my code) and that jar depends on 3 other jar so I have to create binding for all 4 of them. So do you have any idea how can I skip other 3 bindings.

Comment: I think you should be fine creating the bindings only for the jar file that you actually need to use. When you add the jar files to your bindings project, there's a build option that you can set that defines if the bindings will be generated or if the jar file will only be included. So you would set the library that you actually need to access from your code to generate the bindings and set the other 3 to only be included. (I don't recall the exact options)